# Not able to update EF 6.1.1 to EF 6.0.2

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Stuck with a problem .
This morning i was trying to install Nido framework provided by Microsoft community in visual studio 2013. I found the  following issue. I m not getting this EF 6.0.2version . How can i proceed. I have pasted below the error instance, kind advice.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try to uninstall EntityFramework from the PackageManager completely and then install NidoFramwork. You can not "update" to an older version but if there is no newer version installed, NuGut can just install the older one.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the main reason you can not revert to an old version is that you have the newest version of `EntityFramework.Extended` library. Try to uninstall this package and then revert to the older version of EF. You should be able to install corresponding version of `EntityFramework.Extended` library when you revert your `EntityFramework` version.